# Crash in FinalizeUnits [finalization of Classes.pas]

Tags: delphi, crash

My application gets struck in an infinite loop in the finalization section in classes.pas (Delphi 2010) when calling `ReleaseObjectInstanceBlocks`.

`ReleaseObjectInstanceBlocks` calls `GetFreeInstBlockItemCount(InstFreeList, Block)` and the problem seems to be in the `InstFreeList` linked list. The function traverses that list, and it seems the list is pointing to a circular reference (and creates an infinite loop).

Any pointers on how do I find out what is causing an error at this stage?  (All my forms have been freed by this time obviously)

#### Update & More Details

I have located the problem to be a conflict between `Owner` & `Parent`. I construct a form *(which I use as a "frame" by placing it on a panel)* using 
 `constructor TfrSMDControl.Create(AOwner:TComponent; AParent:TWincontrol; id:TStepperMotorDrive);` which creates a few ActiveX components in runtime.

The crash occurs given two conditions

1. if the frame is created with different Owner and parent. e.g., `frSMD := TfrSMDControl.Create(MainForm, Panel1, idControl);`
2. An exception occurs in the destructor code (in which case Delphi tries to free this object a second time -even though the error is caught using a try except block).

I free the object with a `FreeAndNil(frSMD)` using the following destructor

`try
    CWDIO.Free;
    CWPulse.Free;
    CWDAQTools.Free;
  except on e:exception do
    MyDBG.LogException(E.Message);
  end;`

No crash occurs if the frame is created with `frSMD := TfrSMDControl.Create(nil, Panel1, idControl);` (with the same destructor exception handling code).

`CWxxx` are all Ole/ActiveX components. Is there an issue with how Delphi handles ownership of and exception in OleControls ?)

Answer (score 1):

The shared global structure supporting `MakeObjectInstance` has been corrupted. With probability very close to 1 this is because your program breaks the VCL threading model. Somewhere in your program you are calling VCL code in a thread other than the main thread.

Comment: This is a multithreaded program, but visual components are used only in the main thread. (I also have   `Application.UpdateFormatSettings := false` and `Application.UpdateMetricSettings := false;` (to avoid thread conflicts with respect to `TFormatStrings`). Will review the code in detail and post back if I find anything

Comment: You obviously don't intend to call MakeObjectInstance away from the GUI thread but thee evidence suggests that you do. You could use a modified classes unit with some instrumentation.

Comment: The problem isn't caused by the multi-threading (I removed all the secondary threads, and only have the main thread running now, and still get the same crash). My attempt to use a modified 'classes.pas' didn't go very well (I get error messages; e.g., 'controls.pas was compiled with a different version of classes.pas'). Continue to work on this.

Comment: Perhaps you are corrupting the heap in some other way

Comment: I have added more details about what I have figured out (as an update to the question). Looks like there is the conflict between `parent` and `owner` in releasing an Ole control. Everything works fine when owner is `nil`

Comment: This question is long since done. If you want detailed help on a specific repro, that's a new question